How can I temporarily increase the jump power of my character in Unity for a specific duration?
I'm facing an issue with the jump mechanics in my Unity game. Currently, the jump power isn't working as intended. What I want to achieve is to allow my character to jump twice as high as normal for a duration of 5 seconds.
I attempted to implement this using the Invoke method combined with yield return new WaitForSeconds(seconds). However, it doesn't seem to be producing the desired effect.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class JumpController : MonoBehaviour
{   
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    [SerializeField] int jumpPower;
    [SerializeField] float fallMultiplier;

    public Transform GroundCheck;
    public LayerMask groundLayer;
    bool isGrounded;
    Vector2 vecGravity;

    void Start()
    {
        vecGravity = new Vector2(0, -Physics2D.gravity.y);
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {   
        isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCapsule(GroundCheck.position, new Vector2(1.8f, 0.3f), CapsuleDirection2D.Horizontal, 0, groundLayer);

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpPower);
        }

        if(rb.velocity.y < 0)
        {
            rb.velocity -= vecGravity * fallMultiplier * Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {    
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("item") && (collision.gameObject.name == "bounce"))
        {
            jumpPower = 12;
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        }
    }
}


Depends a bit on your exact requirements / desired behaviour.
One simple way to achieve this would be a simple reset invoke
[SerializeField] private float defaultJumpPower;

private jumpPower;

private void Start()
{
    ResetJumpPower();
}

private void ResetJumpPower()
{
    jumpPower = defaultJumpPower;
}

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{    
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("item") && (collision.gameObject.name == "bounce"))
    {
        jumpPower = 12;
        Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        Invoke(nameof(ResetJumpPower), powerUpDuration);
    }
}

Disadvantage is though: If in the meantime you trigger a second power up the Invoke timer is not reset and still resets according to the first power up item.
You can avoid this by first also issue a
CancelInvoke(nameof(ResetJumpPower));
Invoke(nameof(ResetJumpPower), powerUpDuration);

which ensures that only one Invoke is pending at a time.

Alternatively you could use a timer
private float jumpResetTimer;

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{    
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("item") && (collision.gameObject.name == "bounce"))
    {
        jumpPower = 12;
        Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        jumpResetTimer = powerUpDuration;
    }
}

private void Update()
{
    ....

    if(jumpResetTimer > 0)
    {
        jumpResetTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        if(jumpResetTimer <= 0)
        {
            ResetJumpPower();
        }
    }
}

Here if you trigger a second power-up it will just reset the timer so the effect counts for longer

And you could achieve the same also using a Coroutine like e.g.
private Coroutine jumpPowerUpRoutine;

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{    
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("item") && (collision.gameObject.name == "bounce"))
    {
        Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        
        if(jumpPowerUpRoutine != null) StopCoroutine(jumpPowerUpRoutine);

        jumpPowerUpRoutine = StartCoroutine(JumpPowerUpRoutine());
    }
}

private IEnumerator JumpPowerUpRoutine()
{
    jumpPower = 12;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(powerUpDuration);
    jumpPower = defaultJumpPower;
    jumpPowerUpRoutine = null;
}


If you do want to use  a coroutine you should be able to use the below code:
private Coroutine resetPowerUpRoutine;

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("item") && (collision.gameObject.name == "bounce"))
    {
        jumpPower = 12;
        Destroy(collision.gameObject);

        StartResetPowerUp();
    }
}

private void StartResetPowerUp(float waitTime = 5f, int powerUpValue = 6)
{
    if (resetPowerUpRoutine != null)
    {
        StopCoroutine(resetPowerUpRoutine);
    }

    resetPowerUpRoutine = StartCoroutine(ResetPowerUp(waitTime, powerUpValue));
}

private IEnumerator ResetPowerUp(float waitTime = 5f, int powerUpValue = 6)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
    jumpPower = powerUpValue;
}

